# Batch for Automated Setup

Tags: command-line, scripting, batch-file

I just started playing around to Batch scripts and I was wondering if anybody who is familiar with bash or scripting can give me a great reference.

Right now, I am trying to run DiskPart, but another window pops up for it. Can I pass commands to it so it is automated and close out of it automated?

I was also wondering if it is possible to silently run exe files with a Bash script (e.g. install a JRE) and also run multiple EXE files?

Thank you!!

Comment: Are you sure you mean *bash* and not *batch*?

Comment: yes sorry you are right. I meant Batch script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I pass commands to it so it is automated and close out of it automated.

It is a question? Did you try to call `diskpart /?`?

The answer is `diskpart /s "full_path_to_diskpart_script_file"`

Where `full_path_to_diskpart_script_file` is plain text file with DiskPart commands.

> I was also wondering if it is possible to silently run exe files with a Bash script (e.g. install a JRE) and also run multiple EXE files.

Another question? Look at `start /?`

For example, you may run from batch

`start /min "Installing JRE" "full_path_to\jre-7u5-windows-x64.exe" /s`

[JRE Installer Options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/silent-136552.html)

Comment: Thank you for that response. when giving the script file for the diskpart do I just give it another Batch File? Also, I tried the running the JRE Install /min. Is it possible that I can pass the .exe commands? When I said run silently, i meant without user input at all.

Comment: You run the .exe and then it starts the Windows Installer to install the JRE. I was hoping I could just check boxes and uncheck boxes and press next etc. by passing it an sequantial command or something.

Comment: Again. What exe you are running?